# Replicate android folder structure preserving folder date and time

Tags: file-management

I have a samsung galaxy S8 SM-G950W. I want to replicate exact date and time of folders all 3 date and time fields (date created, date modified, date accessed) from within my s8 into my desktop PC. The s8 is not rooted, it is snapdragon CPU. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy photos to new Samsung Galaxy S22 and maintain time/date stamps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246032/copy-photos-to-new-samsung-galaxy-s22-and-maintain-time-date-stamps)

Comment: Do I need to use CMD (admin or not) or android studio? Also, I dont have a micro sd card as the sim try is slightly broken so I cannot pull it out to put in a micro sd card. The folders/files are on my galaxy s8 internal storage.

Comment: I tried adb today and when i pull a file or folder from my android to PC, the date modified and date accessed remain preserved but the date created changes to the current date and time. I have even tried filezilla but same problem

Comment: Related for future readers (since you have found it by yourself): [Is there a way to backup contents of internal SD, while preserving the file's modification date?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/61487/44325)

Comment: what is created date? https://www.howtogeek.com/517098/linux-file-timestamps-explained-atime-mtime-and-ctime/

Comment: date created on windows when right clicking on a photo and then clicking properties. 

What if i install linux on hard drive and then format a usb into ext4 and then try to copy folders and photos ...will that preserve the date and time stamp?

Also, where do i get tar on android? how do I use those steps outlined in the howtogeek.com link ? or are their steps done with android connected to a linux system ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB pull stops after first error](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226573/adb-pull-stops-after-first-error)

Comment: what you mean is `mtime` it represents the date of when the picture (content) was created. what you see in windows is the birth `crtime` when file (bin) was created on disk. that date is irrelevant. the link just explains *"The Difference Between atime, mtime, and ctime*"

Comment: I prefer to work with windows, not linux. Also, that link https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226573/adb-pull-stops-after-first-error does not seem to answer my question becuse, im looking to preserve 3 dates and their respective times, when I use adb, date created (birth time) changes to current date & time which is not what I want

Comment: I know this is kinda late but I found a few workarounds which is still incomplete but hey better than nothing. So basically this method will only work for folders/subfolders which have photos and videos. Create a main folder in the root directory of your android phone, copy the folder you intend to preserve the date and time into that folder then make a zip archive using solid explorer or filemanagerplus and transfer that zip archive or copy archive to windows 10/11 pro and extract using winzip.

Comment: It didn't work, the times for date created and date modified and date accessed are still -1 seconds short of the actual time within android. Does anyone have a solution to preserving the exact second and "expanding" date modified into date created and date accessed?