# I want to transfer all my recordings done AND KEEP the date of creation with my huawei P30 lite to my Oppo Reno7 5G/Find X5 Lite

Tags: data-recovery, huawei, data-transfer, voice-recording, oppo

I transfered all my data from my Huawei to my oppo without any trouble, except my recordings. I was able to transfere them but the date of creation was reset. I really want to keep this information, but I haven't found a way. I already transfered my recordings from my Huawei P20 lite to my huawei P30 lite in April, and when I look in the file, all my recordings older than April 2021 has their date set to 13.04.21, but the date is the good one in the recordings app. It makes me really wonder where this information is stored.
I hope this is clear, don't hesitate to ask for more information.
Good day and thank you for taking the time to read this.
[image]

[image]

Comment: There are multiple ways to preserve file attributes (including timestamps) while copying files. Creating and extracting [`tar`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) archive is one of them. You can use Termux on both sides.

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [Is there a way to backup contents of internal SD, while preserving the file's modification date?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/61487/44325)